# jQuery animation infinite doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I've got this code

```
var goRight = function() {
  $(this).animate({'left:' '40px'}, 1000, goLeft);
};

var goLeft = function() {
  $(this).animate({'left:' '-40px'}, 1000, goRight);
};

var main = function() {
  $('.square').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
$('.square').goRight();
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

It supposed to move the square(a div) to the right then back to the left infinitely and make it blue when the user hovers over it. But it doesn't work. The problem is probably in the `goRight` and `goLeft`, functions. Since if I remove them completely the hover changes the color fine. And when these functions are there nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the chaining like this

```js
$.fn.goRight = function() {
  this.animate({
    'left': '40px'
  }, 1000, function() {
    $(this).goLeft()
  });
  return this;
};

$.fn.goLeft = function() {
  this.animate({
    'left': '-40px'
  }, 1000, function() {
    $(this).goRight()
  });  
  return this;
};

var main = function() {
  $('.square').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
  $('.square').goRight();
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background:black;position:relative;" class="square"></div>
```

For more about jQuery plugin development : https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Just as a side note, a jQuery prototype method should return matched set to keep chaining: `return this.animate(...);`

Comment: There is still issue regarding toggling the class when animation run due to browser (chrome at least) not firing `mouseenter/mouseover` (hover method callbacks) without moving the mouse but this is a well known bug where i think there is no fix AFAIK  See: http://jsfiddle.net/9tp6xwkx/

Comment: @A.Wolff :  oops... that's a major bug